# Can't see added bibliography on latex file, what is wrong?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker, ieeetran, ieeeconf

I am not able to include the bib file I have (file is cool.bib), it works in another latex project I have, but on this one, something is just not working, I am using TexMaker for it.
Please help me understand why it doesn't show anything, and why if I use cite it shows [?].
thanks

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{name of paper\\
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{other guy}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name me}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}

\maketitle
\nocite{*}

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
text bla bla \cite{graph} bla.


\section*{Acknowledgment}

template

\section*{Literature}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}%
\bibliography{cool}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

blg

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: paper4.aux
Reallocating 'name_of_file' (item size: 1) to 5 items.
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file paper4.aux
You've used 2 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            86 strings with 497 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There was 1 error message)
```

Comment: have you run bibtex to generate the bibliography?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you mean on the build, I am doing quickbuild: pdflatex->biblatex->pdflatex x2 -> view pdf

Comment: that is your error then, your document is not using biblatex, you need pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that it is the same since it Texmaker it says: "PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLatex(2x) + View Pdf" which means it probably accepts both

Comment: if bibtex failed to produce a bibliography it will leave errors in the bibtex log (`.blg`) so you could post that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just added that

Comment: move `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`  after `\begin{document}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why doing the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` business. You just want to modify `\refname`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{graph,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2021},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}

\begin{document}

\title{name of paper\\
\thanks{Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.}
}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{other guy}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{name me}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}

\maketitle
\nocite{*}

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
text bla bla \cite{graph} bla.


\section*{Acknowledgment}

template

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents*` just to make the example self-contained, you can continue to use your `.bib` file.

[image]

You can notice that I removed the lines

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

They're completely useless (and wrong).